# What's the meaning of the different "removing leading slash" warnings?

Tags: tar

I'm using gnu `tar` with a few instances of `--exclude` specified.

I get both the

```
Removing leading / from member names
```

and

```
Removing leading / from hard link targets
```

warnings.  What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 10):

No entry within a tarball may begin with a "/", i.e. have an absolute path. It's a security feature, so that if you unpack the tarball, you can be sure that all files will reside in the target directory and subdirectories, instead of being scattered all over the system (and possibly overwriting critical files).

The warnings you see result from `tar` stripping the leading "/" from any absolute paths, both for normal files ("member names") and hard links ("hard link targets").

For example, this command...

```
/home/user $ tar czf tarball.tgz /home/user/data
```

...would result in those warnings, as "/home/..." is converted into "home/...". Unpacking the tarball...

```
/home/user $ tar xzf tarball.tgz
```

...would result in all files being unpacked to `/home/user/home/user/data`. If `tar` hadn't stripped the leading slashes, the files in `/home/user/data` would have been overwritten instead.

Comment: `tar` archives *are* allowed to have absolute names, the stripping can be disabled with `-P` if necessary... It should probably also be noted that *tar* archives store hard links in a similar manner to symlinks -- the second and further links actually point to the first by its *path* (not by inode), which is why the second message is displayed.

Comment: @grawity: Uhhhh... let's say it's *possible* to disable the stripping. It's about as "allowable" as unpacking thousands of files in the current directory. ;-)

Comment: I understood the reason for stripping the slash, why it's the default, etc, but didn't know that the key difference in the two warnings was "normal files" vs "hard links".  Thanks (and to grawity too).

Comment: I ran into it when I specified 2 dirs starting with `/`. It somehow gives the second message in such a case, e.g. `tar czf a.tar.gz /a/a /a/b`. And it doesn't seem to be about hard links. At least not in my case. Maybe it tries to circumvent some issue with hard links, but doesn't care to distinguish hard links for non-hard links.